Is there any event available for when customer side reorder button click?
I need to remove a product while reorder button clicked certain condition. For example if the product sku is 'ABCD' means, i need to remove it from adding cart and all other ordered product need to added in cart.

You have to work on Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder:: execute() controller Action.
  <?php namespace 
 StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

  use Magento\Framework\Registry;

  class Reorder {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
 */
private $messageManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
 */
private $cart;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
 */
private $resultRedirectFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
 */
private $orderLoader;

/**
 * @var Registry
 */
private $registry;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface  $orderLoader,
  \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
   \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,  
   Registry $registry     
) {

    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}
public function aroundExecute(
 \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder $subject 
){
  $result = $this->orderLoader->load($subject->getRequest());
    if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
        return $result;
    }
    $order = $this->registry->registry('current_order');
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $cart = $this->cart;
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        try{
           $cart->addOrderItem($item) ;
        }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {  
            if ($this->cart->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    $cart->save();
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
}
}


Generally magento doesn't provided specific event's for that actions, so you need to create around plugin like this.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder">
      <plugin name="reorder_execute_plugin" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Reorderpluginfile" sortOrder="10" />
  </type>
</config>


Now create Reorderpluginfile.php on following locations.
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Reorderpluginfile.php



add code like this :
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder as ReorderHelper;

class Reorderpluginfile {
     protected $orderLoader;
     protected $_coreRegistry;
     private $reorder;
     private $checkoutSession;

     public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
    Registry $registry,
    ReorderHelper $reorderHelper = null,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder $reorder = null,
    CheckoutSession $checkoutSession = null) 
    {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->reorder = $reorder ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder::class);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CheckoutSession::class);
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
 \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder $subject)
   {

      **HERE YOU NEED TO CUSTOMIZATION ACCORDING TO REQUIREMENTS**

      $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
    if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
        return $result;
    }
    $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    try {
        $reorderOutput = $this->reorder->execute($order->getIncrementId(), $order->getStoreId());
    } catch (LocalizedException $localizedException) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($localizedException->getMessage());
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }

    // Set quote id for guest session: \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::save doesn't set quote id
    // to session for guest customer, as it does \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::save which is deprecated.
    $this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($reorderOutput->getCart()->getId());

    $errors = $reorderOutput->getErrors();
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $useNotice = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true);
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $useNotice
                ? $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($error->getMessage())
                : $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getMessage());
        }
    }

    return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
   }

}

